# Handling multiple websocket connections

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm trying to create a program that will connect to several servers though gorilla web-sockets. I currently have a program that will iterate over a list of server addresses and create a new goroutine that will create its own Websocket.conn and handle reading and writing.

The problem is that every time a new goroutine is created the previous goroutines are blocked and only the last one can continue. I believe this is because the gorilla websocket library is blocking each gorotutine, but I might be mistaken.

I have tried putting a timer in the server list iterator and each goroutine will work perfectly but then the moment a new goroutine is made with another address the previous goroutine is blocked.

The relevant bits of my code:

In my `main.go`

```golang
for _, server := range servers {
  go control(ctx, server, port)
}
```

In `control()`

```golang
func control(ctx context.Context, server, port string) { 
  url := url.URL{
    Scheme: "ws",
    Host: server + ":" + port,
    Path: "",
  }
  conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(url.String(), nil)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer conn.Close()
  go sendHandler(ctx, conn)
  go readHandler(ctx, conn)
}

readHandler(ctx context.Context, conn *websocket.Con) {
  for {
    _, p, err := conn.ReadMessage(); if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    select {
      case <-ctx.Done():
        goto TERM
      default:
        // do nothing
    }
  }
  TERM:
  // do termination  
}

sendHandler(ctx context.Context, conn *websocket.Con) {
  for _, msg := range msges {
    err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
  }
  <-ctx.Done()
}
```

I removed the parts where I add waitgroups and other unnecessary pieces of code.

So what I expect is for there to be 3n goroutines running (where n is the number of servers) without blocking but right now I see only 3 goroutines running which are the ones called by the last iteration of the server list.

Thanks!

EDIT 14/06/2019:

I spent some time making a small working example and in the example the bug did not occur - none of the threads blocked each other. I'm still unsure what was causing it but here is my small working example:

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "sync"
    "net/url"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    )

func main() {
    servers := []string{"5555","5556", "5557"}
    comms := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(comms, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, server := range servers {
        wg.Add(1)
        go control(server,
                   ctx,
                   &wg)
    }

    <-comms
    cancel()
    wg.Wait()
}

func control(server string, ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Printf("Started control for %s\n", server)
    url := url.URL {
        Scheme: "ws",
        Host: "0.0.0.0" + ":" + server,
        Path: "",
    }
    conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(url.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    var localwg sync.WaitGroup

    localwg.Add(1)
    go sendHandler(ctx, conn, &localwg, server)
    localwg.Add(1)
    go readHandler(ctx, conn, &localwg, server)

    <- ctx.Done()
    localwg.Wait()
    wg.Done()
    return
}

func sendHandler(ctx context.Context, conn *websocket.Conn, wg *sync.WaitGroup, server string) {
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        err := conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("ping"))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("sent msg to %s\n", server)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
    <- ctx.Done()
    wg.Done()
}

func readHandler(ctx context.Context, conn *websocket.Conn, wg *sync.WaitGroup, server string) {
    for {

        select {

            case <- ctx.Done():
                wg.Done()
                return
            default:
                _, p, err :=  conn.ReadMessage()
                if err != nil {
                    wg.Done()
                    fmt.Println("done")
                }
                fmt.Printf("Got [%s] from %s\n", string(p), server)
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it with dpallot's [simple-websocket-server](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server) by a server on 5555, 5556 and 5557 respectively.

Comment: `sendHandler` and `readHandler` aren't shown, so, who knows, could be anything. I do know that, since you `defer conn.Close()` then start two goroutines that use `conn` before immediately returning (thus closing the connection), those functions won't be able to use `conn` at all.

Comment: As noted in the post I have waitgroups that would prevent the `defer conn.Close()` from running before `sendHandler` and `ReadHandler` terminate. I can add `sendHandler` and `ReadHandler` but they are very simple functions.

Comment: These aren't the only relevant parts of the code. A proper [mcve] will allow someone to replicate the issue as described

Comment: The program in the question will exit with a panic in one of the handler functions. Post actual code. Gorilla connections are independent of each other.  A method call on one connection will not cause some other connection to block.

Comment: Added a minimal reproducible example, It does not have the same blocking issue. I'm not entirely confident on what the bug was but thanks for telling me to make the example! ^

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is causing the problem:

```
conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(url.String(), nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer conn.Close()
go sendHandler(ctx, conn)
go readHandler(ctx, conn)
```

You create the connection, defer the close of it, start two other goroutines and then end the function.  The function end closes the socket due to your defer.

Comment: I removed the `defer conn.Close()` and the same thing happens, as soon as one new goroutine creates a new websocket the other one blocks. I'm trying to get a small example but its a bit challenging since I need to find some example servers.